# Metro Style App HttpWebRequest Headers doesn't contain a definition for Add

Tags: httpwebrequest, microsoft-metro, custom-headers

I want to add custom header/value pair into HttpWebRequest object's headers collection. I can add custom header/value pair into the collection in WPF application like this.

```
HttpWebRequest HWR = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("........");
WHR.Headers.Add("Header", "Value");
```

But!

When I use the same code in a Metro Style App, an error as title rises. How am I supposed to add custom header/value pair into headers collection?

Thank you...

Comment: have you tried `WHR.Headers["Header"] = "Value";`

Comment: No. Because I want to add something else, other than in the standard headers list. For example ...Headers.Add("SomeID", "SomeValue").

Comment: From what I remember - custom headers were not allowed and in fact you could not even see all the headers when reading http responses.

Comment: I can add custom headers in this way and get them by **Request.Headers.GetValues(string)** method in a WPF application.